# Reward for women wearing Tzizit

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, women, tzitzis

There is a general rule that a person who is not obligated cannot do a mitzvah on behalf of someone who is obligated, and according to at least one Rishon this is because a person who is obligated has a stronger Yetzer Hara, and the more difficulty someone has with a Mitzvah the more reward they get.

Since the person not obligated receives less reward, they cannot do it on behalf of someone who's baseline mitzvah receives more.

But what about Tzizit?

A person is not obligated to wear Tzizit unless he wears a four-cornered garment. Therefore he's not Chayiv in the mitzvah until he puts on the four-cornered garment. A person doesn't have the Yetzer Hara to take off the Tzizit from the garment.

So would women, who are not obligated in Tzizit, receive the same amount of reward as men, who are obligated? In this case, since the level of difficulty is the same, wouldn’t the reward be the same?

(I'm not asking if they can put on Tzizit for men just whether it makes sense that the reward level should be the same)

Comment: Notably, this logic would only apply if this the sole reasoning behind the Rabbinic dictum.  Other commentators provide additional/alternate reasons.

Comment: No. They are not the same level. Once the man wears a four-cornered garment, he becomes obligated to put tzitzit on it; not so with women. Wearing a four-cornered garment is *not* obligatory; putting tzitzit on it is. Women, either way, are not obligated at all so they have no yetzer there while a man does(because nobody likes being forced to do something). Becoming obligated in something makes it harder to do it.

Comment: @chacham Nisan but when does the Yetzer Hara take effect? Before you put it on youre not yet Chayiv. And once you put it on you already have the mitzvah. And who has the Yetzer Hara to take off the titzis strings? That's my point

Comment: @wfb same to you

Comment: @Orion Mexican ponchos are pretty cool. It's easier to wear one without tzitzit than to have to wait to put tzitzit on it. A woman could wear it as is!

Comment: @Chacham Nisan isn't that a rather minute case? Regardless you realize you're saying the Yetzer Hara is kicking in before youre Chayiv right?

Comment: @Orion Yes; which is pretty much always the case.

Comment: "I'm not asking if they can put on Tzizit for men just whether it makes sense that the reward level should be the same" Based on how you set up the question, isn't the answer automatically yes? You're working with the baseline that a) reward is based on difficulty and b) difficulty for Tzitzis is equal for men and women. Therefore, c)  men and women receive the same reward for Tzitzis, has to follow. One can argue with the a) and b), but if those are being taken for granted as per the question, wouldn't c) automatically follow?

Comment: @salmononius I'm seeing if anyone can contradict b.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misconceptions in your question.

Firstly, it is true that it is considered more worthy for someone obligated to do a mitzva than for someone who isn't obligated. But there is an unrelated, separate principle that

> Whoever is not obligated to do a certain matter cannot discharge the
>   obligation on behalf of the community.

([Rosh Hashana 29b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.29b))

Secondly, a mitzva that has to be done with the body (חובת הגוף), can only be done by the person themself. The concept of agency (שליחות) doesn't help. (For example, I can appoint an agent to marry a woman for me, but not to do circumcision on my behalf...)

Finally, while it's true that the mitzva of tzitizit is optional since one doesn't have to wear a four-cornered garment, if a man and a woman both wear one, the former is obligated in tzitzit while the latter is not. So the level of obligation is not equivalent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not asking whether a women can wear tzizit for a man as like you said you can't do a bodily mitzvah for somone else. It's as Double AA commented above that I'm asking about wether it makes sense that they would get equal reward.

Comment: @Orion if everyone is misunderstanding your question then please edit it to clarify! what are you waiting for?

Comment: @Orion I answered that as well in my last paragraph